# Cakephp 3 Time format - removing hours

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I wanted to as, hoc can i format time, from database table. Now i get:

2015-07-01 00:00:00

Question is, how use Cakephp3 goodies to have :

2015-07-01

I have tried examples from docs, but with no success.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

When having a Time object you can do this

```
$timeObject->format('Y-m-d')
```

Comment: How can i use this in View ? What is proper way to config this ? Thank You

Comment: Yes, you can. What do you want to configure exactly?

Comment: How can i sue this:$timeObject->

Comment: I don't understand your question.